# Laravel 5: replace parameter value then retrieve URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there a way to change one or more "Route's parameters", and re-build URL based on the modified parameters, ex: change "$page" value.

I tried many ways:

```
Route::current()->setParameter('page', ++$page);
// also try
Request::route()->setParameter('page',  ++$page);
```

but always when re-request, URL:

```
$request->path(); //return path with origin parameter value
$request->url(); //return path with origin parameter value
```

Is there a way to replace "parameter" value then retrieve URL with updated value?
thanks,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: update page in URL: ..home/category/1 => ..home/category/2  (Note: page not must at the end of URL)

Comment: And return next page URL in the response,

Comment: This logic has to be done inside the controller. You can pass arguments as `{page}` in routes and then add that to controller like `RouteController(Request $request, $page) {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle it this way: (in controller function)

```
    Request::route()->setParameter('page', ++$page); //new parameter value
    $parameters = Route::current()->Parameters();
    $uri = Route::current()->uri();
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '/{'));

    $full_url = Request::fullUrl();
    $full_url = substr($full_url, 0, strpos($full_url, $uri));
    $full_url = $full_url.$uri.'/'.implode('/',$parameters);
    return $full_url;
```

Steps:

1. Update parameter value.
2. Clear origin route from parameters.
3. Clear full URL from intersected folders with "origin route".
4. Re-construct the URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = Request::url(); // url without query
$query = Request::query(); // query

//Replace parameter:
$newFullUrl = $url.'?'. http_build_query(array_merge($query, ['parameter' => 'value']);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.